# Why my Django application get 404 bad request when send blob to server side using MediaStreamRecorder.js?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am using MediaStreamRecorder.js to make an audio recording with Django. When the user presses the stop button, it will send blob to the server side (Django) and save it to database. However, I receive a 404 bad request when finished recording. I try to print the blob value in views.py, it gives me **none**. I tried many solutions but still cannot fix it. I really need some help.

[image: the blob that send to server side has nothing in it]

I used xhr to send blob for the first try, but it gives me 404 bad request.

chat_script.html -> with js functions

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xhr)
xhr.open('POST', '/record-audio/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
xhr.setRequestHeader("MyCustomHeader", "Put anything you need in here, like an ID");
xhr.send(blob);
```

Currently I am using fetch but still getting the same error.

chat_script.html -> with js functions

```
function sendData(blob) {
                const csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken')
                fetch('/record-audio/', {
                    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token},
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: blob,
                });
                console.log('success')
            } 
            sendData(blob)
```

It prints 'success' in the console, however the next message it twll me is 404 bad request.

**For the '/record-audio/' in xhr.open('POST', '/record-audio/', true); and fetch('/record-audio/', I actually type in only '/record-audio' when I first try, but it keeps giving me the error Not Found: /record-audio/record-audio/**

urls.py

```
path('record-audio/',views.record_audio,name="record_audio"),
```

record.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Recorder</h1>

<section class="experiment" >
  <br>
  <h3>
    Send Message: Speech to text
  </h3>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'record_audio' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <button id="start-recording">Start</button>
    <button id="pause-recording" disabled>Pause</button>
    <button id="resume-recording" disabled>Resume</button>
    <button id="stop-recording" disabled>Stop</button>
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="save file"> -->
  </form>
  
</section>

<section class="experiment">
    <div id="audios-container"></div>
</section> 

{% include "chat_script.html" %}
<script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/MediaStreamRecorder.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.3.js' %}"></script>
<!-- <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>  -->
<!-- <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>  -->

  <!-- <div>
    <audio id="audio-player" controls></audio>
  </div> -->

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def record_audio(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("Hi2")
        return render(request, 'recording/record.html')
    blob= request.FILES.get("blob", None)
    print(blob)
    if blob is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Missing audio-blob parameter") 
    audio_blob = request.body
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    filename = f"{request.user.username}_{now}.wav"
    audio_file = AudioFile(name=filename, user=request.user)
    audio_file.audio_blob = audio_blob
    audio_file.save()
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

models.py

```
class AudioFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    audio_blob = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.audio_filename = self.audio.name
        super(AudioFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Audio Files"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.audio_filename
```

I try to download blob from the client side and it does working. But I can't send it to server side.
[image: 404 error]